# How to reference specific asset subfolders in Craft 3

Tags: templating, craft3, assets

I am having trouble referencing specific subfolders in Assets in Craft 3 using Twig.  The query that I've written is still showing all content, when I only want it to show content from a specific subfolder.

The folder layout: /files/asset-volume/subfolder/file.txt

When I try this query code, I still get all of the files from the volume, when I only want the subfolder.  How do I only reference the specific subfolder?

```
{% set subFolders = craft.assets()
                    .volume('asset-volume')
                    .includeSubfolders('subfolder')
                    .all()
%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `folderId` parameter. https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/asset-queries.html#parameters

To find which id your folder has, it looks like you have to look in the `assets` table - someone might have an easier solution.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the folderId parameter, but to get that to work with what I'm doing I'd have to do some finagling.  I did something similar with jQuery.